# CDK Env property ignored

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

Many articles suggest simply explicitly setting the `env` property for your CDK stack in order to specify the account and region of where the stack will be deployed. E.g.

```
new MyStack(app, 'MyStack', {
  stackName: 'MyStack',
  env: {
    account: '123456789', 
    region: 'us-west-2' 
  }
});
```

However, setting the `env` property seems to take no effect when I issue `cdk deploy`. The stack gets deployed in the account region specified in my default AWS profile.

I've also made sure that I'm propagating the `props` to the parent constructor. I.e.

```
export class MyStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.App, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props); // passing props to the parent here

    ...
```

I'm really not sure how to explicitly specify the region of my stack.

---

Edit: additional info

`manifest.json` excerpt:

```json
"MyStack": {
    "type": "aws:cloudformation:stack",
    "environment": "aws://unknown-account/unknown-region"
```

Comment: Your expectations are correct.  An explicit env prop [takes precedence](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/environments.html) over the default profile's env.  Did you re-compile your code with `tsc` after making the change?  FYI, the synthed stack environments will be recorded in `cdk.out > manifest.json`.

Comment: Thanks @fedonev, I tried issuing `tsc` and deploying again, but still didn't work. Are we expected to issue `tsc` every time we make a code change? I've only been issuing `cdk synth` to check for syntax before `cdk deploy`.


I also took a look at the `manifest.json` file, it's showing the stack environment as unknown. So seems like it didn't pick up the `props`? I.e.

`"MyStack": {
      "type": "aws:cloudformation:stack",
      "environment": "aws://unknown-account/unknown-region",`

Comment: The `aws://unknown-account/unknown-region` confirms that the CDK isn't seeing your env.  Please edit your question with the full `app.ts`, `cdk.json` and your `cdk deploy` command.

Comment: You must always build the Typescript after each change.  There are many ways to do this.  For example, you can add `"build": "tsc"` to `cdk.json` to have the CDK compile the Typescript before each synth.

Comment: @fedonev I got it to work, but I don't feel like it's the correct way. I randomly stumbled upon `bin/my-cdk-stack.ts`, with this comment: `/* Uncomment the next line if you know exactly what Account and Region you
   * want to deploy the stack to. */
  // env: { account: '123456789012', region: 'us-east-1' },`. When I uncomment the line and specify it with my desired region, it works.

Comment: Are we supposed to edit the `.ts` file in the `bin` folder directly? Based on the comment shown, it seems to suggest CDK expects us to specify the account/region there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251444/discussion-between-bluebucket7-and-fedonev).

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you are missing to bootstrap your AWS environment.

Please check the details here: [Bootstrapping your AWS environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cli.html#cli-bootstrap)

Comment: Thanks Dossani, but I've already issued bootstrap to my desired environments. I also believe there would be an error if the environment wasn't bootstrapped correctly, which is not my case.